# Criteria on a set of strings

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate 3.6, and I have a class Shop with a field alternateCodes of type Set<String>, that is mapped as follows:

```
<set cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true" name="alternateCodes"
     table="shops_alternateCodes">
    <key column="SHOP_ID" not-null="true"/>
    <element column="CODE" length="32" not-null="true" type="string"
             unique="true"/>
</set>
```

and I would like to build a Criteria that would search a Shop that as an alternateCodes that contains some string.

The HQL equivalent would be something like this:

```
from Shop s join s.alternateCodes c where c=?
```

How can I express this using the criteria API?

Thanks in advance

P.S.

I have tried this:

```
            teria = getPm().createCriteria(Shop.class);
            ...
            teria.createAlias("alternateCodes", "acode");
            teria.add(Restrictions.eq("acode", code));
```

but of course, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.createCriteria(Shop.class)
.createAlias("alternateCodes", "alternateCodes")
.add(Restrictions.in("acode", code))
```

Comment: not possible: Restrictions.in needs a collection as the second argument. It's the other way around.